# Merge observables on one type and then chain to obserbable of another type

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Are there solutions for chaining Observables of different types?
I want to `merge` Observables, and when each of them sends the `Completed` event, emit the next Observable (`signal`).

Something similar to `ReactiveCocoa`'s `then`.

```
let signal = Observable<String>.create { observer in
    observer.onCompleted()
    return Disposables.create()
}

let signals: [Observable<Int>] = [Observable.just(1), Observable.just(2), Observable.just(3)]

Observable.from(signals).merge().concat(signal).subscribe {
    print("completed")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this by `takeLast(1)` and then `flatMap` to needed Observable.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `Element` needs to be known, so you have a few options I can think of:

1. Make the type `Any`, which both `Int` and `String` can be.
2. Add protocol conformance to `Int` and `String` which can expose the common interface you're wanting to use on them.
3. Make the type an `enum` which has cases for both `Int` and `String`.

Here's an implementation of each of those options:

#### With `Any`:

```
let withAny = PublishSubject<Any>()

withAny.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

withAny.onNext(1)
withAny.onNext("a")
```

> 1
> a

#### With some `protocol`:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    // put whatever interface from the elements in here
}
extension String : SomeProtocol {}
extension Int : SomeProtocol {}

let withProtocol = PublishSubject<SomeProtocol>()

withProtocol.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

withProtocol.onNext(2)
withProtocol.onNext("b")
```

> 2
> b

#### With some `enum`:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case int(Int)
    case str(String)
}

let withEnum = PublishSubject<SomeEnum>()

withEnum.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

withEnum.onNext(.int(3))
withEnum.onNext(.str("c"))
```

> int(3)
> str("c")

Comment: What do you think about `takeLast(1)` and then do `flattenMap`

Comment: Yea, that would work as long as your intention is not to use the elements of the original `Observable`, but simply to use it as a way to trigger the second `Observable`.  From your question, it sounded like you actually wanted the elements from both, chained.  If you're intending to use `takeLast` and `flatMap`, then you could even more simply do `concat`.  As long as you're sure you would have gotten at least one element on the original `Observable`, it would have the same effect.